# What are the rules for uniform initialization of a union

Tags: c++, c++11

If i compile the following code ...

```
int main() 
{
    union U
    {
        struct { int i, j; } s;
        long long x, y;
        int z;
    };
    U li { 1 };
}
```

... either x or y becomes initialized with 1 from what I can deduce from the didsassembly. I noticed that when initializing a LARGE_INTERGER with Win32, where the QuadPart becomes initialized, which is very convenient for me.
But what are the rules for static initalization of unions ? Which part of the union is applied with the initialization value if there's no constructor ?
Edit: I've removed the language-lawyer tag someone applied here because I won't judge on that.

Comment: Check this out https://cppinsights.io/s/fac175f6 Your code initializes `li.s` not `li.z`!

Comment: Side note, in C++ you're better of using [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (union has more UB cases than you'd like to know about)

Comment: @PepijnKramer: The code is safe since I'm not aliasing with this example.

Comment: Then consider my answer for other who come looking here. I've seen to many mis-uses of union I guess ;)

Comment: @PepijnKramer: In most cases a variant is the better choice, but actually all compilers support alliasing with a union.

Comment: I just did a quick `union` aliasing experiment with clang/llvm.  The aliasing worked fine, at `-O0`.  The aliasing failed, at `-O3`.  Just need to update your claim to "ignoring all compilers that do not support aliasing with a union, actually all compilers support aliasing with a union."

Comment: @Eljay There's -fno-strict-aliasing. The Linux kernel is compiled with that and this also applies to C++.

Comment: `-fno-strict-aliasing` caused the aliasing to work fine at `-O3`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can see more clearly what is happening with [cppinsights.io](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=aW50IG1haW4oKSAKewogICAgdW5pb24gVQogICAgewogICAgICAgIHN0cnVjdCB7IGludCBpLCBqOyB9IHM7CiAgICAgICAgbG9uZyBsb25nIHgsIHk7CiAgICAgICAgaW50IHo7CiAgICB9OwogICAgVSBsaSB7IDEgfTsKfQo=&insightsOptions=cpp17&std=cpp17&rev=1.0):

```cpp
    U li = {{1, 0}};
```

Using aggregate initialization on a union (without a designator like `{ .x = 1 }`) will only ever initialize the first member of the union.

The reason the first member can be initialized like that is because of [brace elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Brace_elision): `U li { 1 };` becomes `U li { { 1 } };` (and the other member `j` is value initialized to `0`).

Comment: The first member is s and it's a struct.

Comment: @EdisonvonMyosotis Yes and that is what is initialized